# red exclamation mark in android project - however it works fine on my apple

Tags: java, android

I migrated this project from my Apple to MS Windows computer, that is when I get the red exclamation mark. I looked into the problems window and here are the errors I got:

> Archive for required library:
>   'C:/droid/CustomCalenderAndroid/libs/._socialauth-android-2.6.jar' in
>   project 'CustomCalenderAndroid' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP
>   file

and

> Unable to resolve target 'android-17'

Here is what I have tried:

- clean then build all
- created a brand new app on my apple, then migrated to the Windows computer, works fine.
- added the facebookSDK in libraries for this project
- I checked to see if _socialauth-android-2.6.jar was present in my library, and it is indeed there. I thought of deleting it and re-adding it, but it does not give me the option:

[image]

- I clicked on android 4.4 (please look at pic above) and clicked add external jar and just re-added all those jar files, then clean/build yet same error.

Comment: Try renaming the .jar, by removing the first dot. and `Unable to resolve target 'android-17'` usually means that you need to download target api 17, if that is what you are compling with.

Comment: u might want to look at the solution

Answer (score 1):

Red exclamation mark comes if the sdk path is not set properly.For setting the path browase through the files and open the file which contains sdk.

Answer (score 0):

just found the solution: look again at that jar file:

> ._socialauth-android-2.6.jar

I looked at my orginal project lib's folder and there is NO file such as *socialauth-android-2.6.jar being used. I therefore went into my lib folder.. and deleted this file. The .* should have tipped me off that this is some kind of bogus file, it was used at one time in the project a long time ago.. but since then been deleted... yet this ghost still remained.